# Range column use variable (VBA Macro)

Tags: vba

i have a code like this :

```
Dim lastRow As Long

Dim i As Integer
Dim inrange As Range 

lRow = Sheet12.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

Do While Application.CountA(Sheet12.Rows(lRow)) = 0 And lRow <> 1
    lRow = lRow - 1
Loop

lastRow = lRow + 1

For l = 1 To 31
    inrange = Range("A" & lastRow & " , E" & lastRow)** 'when i tried this code error

    Sheet12.Cells(lastRow, l).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    inrange.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    inrange.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    inrange.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    inrange.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Next
```

the error message is  "object variable or with block variable not set", so what should i do. thank's for help.

Comment: Are you trying to set the range `A & lastRow` **to** `E & lastRow`? Yes --> `inrange = Range("A" & lastRow & ":E" & lastRow)` The `For l` loop seems inefficient for what it's trying to do - most lines has nothing to do with `l`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keyword set when assigning a range to a variable. Also I modified your code a little bit I think this is what you are trying to accomplish.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim inrange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheet12

        ' Get the last row.
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To 31
            ' Use the keywprd Set before asigning to an object variable
            ' like a range, worksheet, workbook.
            Set inrange = .Range("A" & lastRow & " , E" & lastRow)   'when i tried this code error

            inrange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            inrange.BorderAround xlContinuous

            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Thanks, I hope this helps :)

Comment: i tried your code didn't show error message but border style not working. i don't know why.... thank you for help me.

Comment: See if it works now. I made a small change to reference the actual sheet.